# Automating Process in AS3

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I've got twenty .swf files and respectively .as extensions of them.

In each file there's my e-mail, but I don't have access to that e-mail anymore, so I want to edit each file to remove it.

Is there any way I can change my e-mail in twenty files and compile them afterwards in an automate process via some script ?

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you using? On a Mac, if you have TextMate, you can do a find->replace in projects - http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_multiple_files#find_and_replace_in_projects - just open all of your .as files in one project, find/replace, save it all.

To mass-compile these, check out gSkinner's Project panel or use this method in CS4/5: http://www.lostinactionscript.com/blog/index.php/2007/04/11/how-to-bulk-publish-flas/

Comment: This sounds like a fine explanation, just wanted to add if you're on a PC with windows you can use Notepad++ (free download works well as Notepad... ++, has a find and replace where you can choose a directory of files to do the text replacement).  In Linux or any *nix enviornment I'd imagine you can use grep... http://forums.devshed.com/unix-help-35/unix-find-and-replace-text-within-all-files-within-a-146179.html I would definitely back up those files before taking any of these steps though as botching an automated replacement could mean losing lots of info.